# SKProductsRequest deallocated, even though using ARC?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, automatic-ref-counting

I'm trying to set up an SKProductsRequest, but I continually get the error EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I know it has to do with ARC.
In my .h file, I have SKProductsRequestDelegate.

These are the main functions in my .m file:

```
- (void)requestProUpgradeProductData {
    NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:kInAppPurchaseProUpgradeProductId];
    productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
    productsRequest.delegate = self;
    [productsRequest start];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark SKProductsRequestDelegate methods

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {
    NSArray *products = response.products;
    //proUpgradeProduct = [products count] == 1 ? [products firstObject] : nil;
    proUpgradeProduct = [products objectAtIndex:0];
    if (proUpgradeProduct) {
        NSLog(@"Product title: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.localizedTitle);
        NSLog(@"Product description: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.localizedDescription);
        NSLog(@"Product price: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.price);
        NSLog(@"Product id: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.productIdentifier);
    }

    for (NSString *invalidProductId in response.invalidProductIdentifiers) {
        NSLog(@"Invalid product id: %@" , invalidProductId);
    }

    // finally release the reqest we alloc/init’ed in requestProUpgradeProductData
    productsRequest = nil;

    [self purchaseProUpgrade];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kInAppPurchaseManagerProductsFetchedNotification object:self userInfo:nil];
}
```

When I enabled NSZombieEnabled, then this is what I get: `"-[InAppPurchaseManager respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance."`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: where do you get the bad access? (you can get an idea of this if you use the debugger with a break point configured to be thrown on an exception)

Comment: I get the bad access right after [productsRequest start] is called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figured it out! The key is when you synthesize the variable, make sure to do it like this:

```
@synthesize productsRequest = _productsRequest;
```

And in the .h, it should look like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) SKProductsRequest *productsRequest;
```

In the .m, make sure to use "self." when using productsRequest:

```
self.productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
self.productsRequest.delegate = self;
[self.productsRequest start];
```

There you go!

Comment: Do you still set self.productsRequest = nil; in
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {

Answer (score 1):

`productsRequest` is being destroyed immediately after `[productsRequest start]`

You need to force a "retain" of `productsRequest` by assigning it to an `__strong` ivar or stuff it in a set, dict or array.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for. But what is the code for that? I have been trying that for the past 2 hours, to no avail..

Comment: I tried doing that by adding "@property (strong) SKProductsRequest *_productsRequest;" into my .h file, but I still get the same error